# Finding KKT conditions for nonlinear optimization problem.

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, nonlinear-optimization, lagrange-multiplier, karush-kuhn-tucker

I have an optimization like below:

$\text{ minimize } \sum_k - \log_2 x_k   $

$\text{subject to: }  x_k \leq q , k =1,2, \cdots, N .$

I can form the Lagrange of the problem as below:

$L(x, \lambda) =  \sum_{k=1}^{N} - \log_2 x_k + \sum_{k=1}^{N} \lambda_k  (x_k -q) $

But How can I find KKT conditions for this? Moreover, How can I solve the problem analytically from there? I know I can solve it through some nonlinear optimization solver software but for now I am only interested in solving the problem analytically so that I can get an exact form of x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The simple solution** (without KKT): it is easy to see that the problem is actually *decoupled*, i.e. the condition $0<x_k\le q$ affects *only one term* $\log_2x_k$ in the objective function. It makes it possible to minimize over $x_k$ each term independently, i.e.
$$
\min\sum_{k=1}^n(-\log_2 x_k)=\sum_{k=1}^n\min_{0<x_k\le q}(-\log_2x_k)=
\sum_{k=1}^n(-\log_2q)=-n\log_2q.
$$
**The "hard" solution** (by KKT): motivate first that the minimum exists. Prove that the boundary $x_k=0$ is never active at the minimum, so we can cut it off to make the set compact, the function is continuous $\Rightarrow$ can apply Weierstrass theorem. Thus, we can use KKT that looks like "$\nabla L=0$ + the complementary slackness conditions + feasibility", i.e. for all $k=1,\ldots,n$
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{lll}
-\frac{1}{x_k\ln 2}+\lambda_k&=&0,\\
\lambda_k(x_k-q)&=&0,\\
\lambda_k\ge 0,\ 0<x_k\le q.
\end{array}
\right.
$$
The first and the third conditions give that $\lambda_k\ne 0$ for all $k$, thus, the second equation gives $x_k=q$. Substitute to the objective function to get $-n\log_2q$.